# Adding Custom Method to JButton class

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a Java Application, I am wanting to format a button as either Active or Inactive (Also possibly a hover method).

The code as I would like to implement it:

```
//Home Tab - Active by default
home = new TabButton();
home.setSize(new Dimension(tabWidth, tabHeight));
home.setFont(getLauncherFont(34));
home.setForeground(Color.white);
home.setText("HOME");
home.setBounds(160, 0, tabWidth, tabHeight);
home.setActive(); --> This Method is what I would like to create
```

I already have a class to create a JButton for the tab:

```
package com.anarcist.minemodloaderv1.skin.components;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;

/**
 *
 * @author anarcist
 */
public class TabButton extends JButton {
    public TabButton() {
        this.setBorderPainted(false);
        this.setFocusPainted(false);
        this.setContentAreaFilled(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.blue);
    }
}
```

I have researched abstract classes. But my TabButton class already extends JButton.

I would like a method like this:

```
public void setActive(){
    this.setBackground(Color.red);
    //Any other changes a want to make regularly
}
```

That can simply be implemented like this `home.setActive();`

My Question I suppose is: Is it easy enough to implement what I am looking for, or will I have to got the long way and set all attributes manually every time?

Comment: I am not sure what u mean but you can extend your TabButton class with every method u want

Comment: Would you please be more precise about what you want exactly? I do not understand very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've described in the post can be done like this:

```
package com.anarcist.minemodloaderv1.skin.components;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;

/**
 *
 * @author anarcist
 */
public class TabButton extends JButton {

    public TabButton() {// initialize

        this.setBorderPainted(false);
        this.setFocusPainted(false);
        this.setContentAreaFilled(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.blue);

    }

    // add your own methods or override JButton methods
    public void setActive(){
       //Add code
       //example: setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should this be implemented like this? `home.setActive()`
I have tested this already, I get an error saying that the method does not exist.

Comment: Yes, it should be implemented like that, are you using an IDE?

Comment: NetBeans. But if I run i get error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: javax.swing.JButton.setActive`

Comment: Issue resolved. I was declaring the home button by `private JButton home;` instead of my custom `private TabButton home;`